# What are the nonegative integral solutions to $k^2 = 2 n^2 +1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the nonegative integral solutions to $k^2 = 2 n^2 +1$?  $n = 2$ and $k = 3$  works, what is the next smallest pair?

Comment: Can you give some context to your question - why do you need to know, what have you tried etc

Comment: This question ultimately boils down to determining [triangular numbers that are also perfect squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number#Pell.27s_equation).

Comment: Why?  To answer to a question posed by Will Shortz (puzzle master of NY Times), originally by Martin Gardner, on Sunday, October 19 AM.

Answer (score 1):

First, take the square root of both:

$\sqrt{k^2}=\sqrt{2n^2+1} \iff |k| = \sqrt{2n^2+1}$. In order to get both variables to positive integers, you need to have $2n^2+1$ to be a square number:

If $n = 1 \iff 2n^2+1 = 3$ and is no square number:

> $n = 1 \iff 2n^2+1 = 3$
>
> $\color{blue}{n = 2 \iff 2n^2+1 = 9} \rightarrow$ which is a square number
>
> $n = 3 \iff 2n^2+1 = 19$
>
> $n = 4 \iff 2n^2+1 = 33$
>
> $n = 5 \iff 2n^2+1 = 51$
>
> $n = 6 \iff 2n^2+1 = 73$
>
> $n = 7 \iff 2n^2+1 = 99$
>
> $n = 8 \iff 2n^2+1 = 129$
>
> $n = 9 \iff 2n^2+1 = 163$
>
> $n = 10 \iff 2n^2+1 = 201$
>
> $n = 11 \iff 2n^2+1 = 243$
>
> $\color{blue}{n = 12 \iff 2n^2+1 = 289} \rightarrow$ which is also a square number

So, the second value for $n = 12$ and $k=\sqrt{2n^2+1}=\sqrt{289}=17$.

Comment: Are there infinitely many solutions? Are they quite rare?